# How To Publish Postman Documentation In A CI/CD Pipeline?

Tags: postman

Im having a problem figuring out how to publish documentation using Bitbucket Pipelines. I am currently able to take my API Schema, Create an API with it, copy it to a collection and then publish that collection so that my end users can see it (I did that following this guide in Postman https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/publishing-your-docs/). However I am trying to automate this process so that I don't have to manually do it every time, but I cannot find any documentation on how this would be done. Does anyone have any idea how to do this or if its even possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.